# Reading json file in a folder structure using angular js

Tags: angularjs, json

I am getting 404 error when i am trying to read .json file from the folder structure as below.

I am using `$http.get('/app/npi/npiList.json')` to read.

[image: Screnshot]

Need to access the Json file from the app.js controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the '/' from the request,

It should be,

```
app.controller("listController", ["$scope","$http",
    function($scope,$http) {   
       $http.get('app/npi/npiList.json').then(function (response){
               console.log(response.data)
        });

}]);
```

Comment: do you have team viewer?